# Train Fare Calculation.Android

Tags: java, android

Currently I am making project that will calculate a user's fare. The calculator will add 5 for every 3 stations from the starting station point to the destination. Currently I am using an `if` else statement. Any idea how can formulate the algorithm? Using `if` and `else` will cost too much code.

Currently this code is what I have so far :

MainActivity.java Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    // uicontrols
    Spinner spStart;
    Spinner spDestination;
    Button btnsubmit;

    //class members
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterBusinessType;

    // local members
    String sdestination,sstart;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        spStart = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spStart);
        spDestination = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spDestination);

        btnsubmit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        btnsubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Initialize and set Adapter

        // Country Item Selected Listener
        spStart.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                                   int position, long id) {
                // On selecting a spinner item
                 sstart = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                // Showing selected spinner item
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Selected Country : " + sstart, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        // Business Type Item Selected Listener
        spDestination.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                                   int position, long id) {
                // On selecting a spinner item
                sdestination = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                // Showing selected spinner item
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Bussiness Type : " + sdestination, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        if(sstart.equals("Recto") && sdestination.equals(("Legarda"))){
                    textView.setText("Single Journey : 15");
                    textView2.setText("Beep Balance : 13");

                }
         else if(sstart.equals("Recto") && sdestination.equals(("Pureza"))){
                    textView.setText("Single Journey : 15");
                    textView2.setText("Beep Balance : 13");

                }
         else if(sstart.equals("Recto") && sdestination.equals(("V Mapa"))){
                textView.setText("Single Journey : 15");
                textView2.setText("Beep Balance : 13");

            }

        else if(sstart.equals("Recto") && sdestination.equals(("J.Ruiz"))){
                    textView.setText("Single Journey : 20");
                    textView2.setText("Beep Balance : 13");

                }
        else if(sstart.equals("Recto") && sdestination.equals(("Gilmore"))){
            textView.setText("Single Journey : 20");
            textView2.setText("Beep Balance : 13");

        }
        else if(sstart.equals("Recto") && sdestination.equals(("Betty Go Belmonte"))){
            textView.setText("Single Journey : 20");
            textView2.setText("Beep Balance : 13");

        }
        else if(sstart.equals("Recto") && sdestination.equals(("Araneta Center Cubao"))){
            textView.setText("Single Journey : 20");
            textView2.setText("Beep Balance : 13");

        }
        else if(sstart.equals("Recto") && sdestination.equals(("Anonas Station"))){
            textView.setText("Single Journey : 25");
            textView2.setText("Beep Balance : 13");

        }
        else if(sstart.equals("Recto") && sdestination.equals(("Katipunan"))){
            textView.setText("Single Journey : 25");
            textView2.setText("Beep Balance : 13");

        }
        else if(sstart.equals("Recto") && sdestination.equals(("Santolan"))){
            textView.setText("Single Journey : 25");
            textView2.setText("Beep Balance : 13");
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: plz post what you have tried so far?

Comment: please see my answer thankyou somuch

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your original question with any additional info you are providing such as code or logs. This site is for Q&A for specific programming problems. You can always delete an answer you wrote if you need to.

Comment: This might better fit on the CodeReview StackExchange

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a giant else/if you could just see how many stations there are between the starting point and the destination and calculate the fare that way.

```
int numStations = getNumStations();
int fare = (numStations / 3) * 5
```

Hope this helps